# How to create multiple images for specific product using django ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, ajax

i'm learning django and i'm trying building ecommerce website , I want to build a system that allows users to upload images to specific product in the store so I tried to pass the id of the product in url parameter and try to access that id from my class based view so I can add images to that item,
but i had always a problem showing up and i can't figure out what is the problem, This my code

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from item.views import ProgressBarUploadView


app_name = 'item'
urlpatterns = [
    path('progress-bar-upload/<int:pk>/', ProgressBarUploadView.as_view(), name='progress_bar_upload'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class ProgressBarUploadView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.kwargs['pk'])   # i want to print pk of product
        photos_list = Photo.objects.all()
        return render(self.request, 'zwwebsite/item_images_creation.html', {'photos': photos_list})


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        time.sleep(1)  
        form = PhotoForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            photo = form.save()
            print(self.kwargs['pk']) # i want to print pk of product
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': photo.file.name, 'url': photo.file.url}
        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

**models.py**

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='media/item_image')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ('file', )
```

**my template**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{% block title %}Photos Library - Simple is Better Than Complex{% endblock %}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
      .page-header {
        margin-top: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>




  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">

      <!--form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Clear Database
    </button>
  </form-->
  <h1 class="page-header">
    Photos
    <small></small>
  </h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h3 class="panel-title">Examples</h3>
        </div>
        <a href="{% url 'item:progress_bar_upload' %}" class="list-group-item{% if request.path == '/progress-bar-upload/' %} active{% endif %}">
          Progress Bar Upload
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>




    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary js-upload-photos">
      <i class="fa fa-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 Upload photos
    </button>
    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" multiple
           style="display: none;"
           data-url="{% url 'item:progress_bar_upload' %}"
           data-form-data='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>
  </div>

  <table id="gallery" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Photo</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for photo in photos %}
        <tr>
          <td><img src="{{ photo.file.url }}" alt="{{ photo.file.name }}"></td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-progress" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Uploading...</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;">0%</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.ui.widget.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.iframe-transport.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.fileupload.js' %}"></script>

    <script src="{% static 'js/progress-bar-upload.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the error that appears to me

[link to the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5rtp.png)

please help me do that stuff and solve that problem